# Collection View Controller spacing of cells

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

How do I remove the padding between cells on a collectionview? (iOS 6)
I have a very small cell, I've looked over the constraints and I cannot see what to change.

What's happening is that the cells have about 1/4in black space between them (thumbnails). I want about 1mm of space between and 4 per row.
I managed to figure out the 4 per row thing, but they have to be so small that theres so much space between them.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this depends how you're creating the UICollectionViewController to start. I personally always use the Story Board approach. If you've done this, select the "Collection View" then open the Size Inspector and adjust the Min Spacing between Cells/Lines. Also make sure, if you have an image in your cell that the image/cell are the same size otherwise it can also introduce a space. If you're doing everything via code, adjust these values when you create the Collection View object.

Comment: ahh yes. There it is. Thank you. Coming from the Microsoft world for the past +decade I need to orient myself in XCode a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. Hadn't seen those teeny properties. Still new-ish at this.